# WPF ListBox send SelectedItem value to the viewmodel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Inside MainWindow there is listbox filled with some data. These data is loaded from viewmodel, so I dont have any codebehind.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxData" 
         DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelDataSource}}" 
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BookTemplate}"                              
         ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" />
```

How can I know which book is selected inside listbox (using `ICommand`) and send it's property (`int Id` for example) to `viewmodel` for further processing?

Comment: Bind `SelectedItem` to some property in ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply bind `SelectedItem` to some property (say *SelectedBook*) in your ViewModel, no need to have *ICommand* for this.

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxData" 
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BookTemplate}"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook}" />
```

You can get Id for the book by simply accessing ViewModel property:

```
int selectedBookId = SelectedBook.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `SelectedBook` property to your `ViewModel` class, preferably of your `Book` type.

Then in your XAML, add the proper `Binding`:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook}"/>
```

If it acts up, you can force it to be a `TwoWay` binding, like so:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

It is imperative that your `SelectedBook` property also invoke the proper `PropertyChanged` notification so the binding keeps the UI and `ViewModel` in sync.

Comment: `SelectedItem` binds two way by default.

Answer (score 0):

Rohit is right

bind the selected item of the listbox to a property that is in the viewmodel:

like this:  (using a property called SelectedBook)

```
 <ListBox Name="listBoxData" 
     DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelDataSource}}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedBook, Mode=TwoWay}"
     ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BookTemplate}"                              
     ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" />
```