# Display ListBox SelectedItem

Tags: .net, wpf

I've just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957732/wpf-listbox-send-selecteditem-value-to-the-viewmodel/20957787#20957787) and I'm having problems with its implementation.

MainWindow has listbox with some data. On selected item inside that listbox I want to display in textblock at status bar on same window selected data is DataOne where DataOne represents Name property.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxData"              
         ItemsSource="{Binding MyListBoxData}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData}" />
```

Inside status bar element

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedData.Name, StringFormat='Selected data is: {0}'}">
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public MyData SelectedData {get; set;}
```

p.s. just to clarify data is properly displayed inside listbox, DataContext is set inside ViewModel constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not implementing the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface in the viewmodel?

You have to do that in order for the binding-system to know when to update the value in the `TextBlock`.

So implement the interface, and then in the setter of the `SelectedData` property raise the `PropertyChanged` event:

```
private MyData _selectedData;
public MyData SelectedData
{
    get { return _selectedData; }
    set
    {
        _selectedData = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedData");
    }
}

private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bind directly to the selected item from the `MyListBoxData` collection like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyListBoxData/Name, StringFormat='Selected data is: {0}'}">
```

If it doesn't work at first, you might need to set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property on the `ListBox` to `True`:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxData" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"             
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyListBoxData}" />
```